# How to monitor ECS task launch loop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, infinite-loop, amazon-ecs

I created a lambda which streams ECS events to CloudWatch [ECS CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet.html). I'm stuck now on how to detect infinite loops of launching tasks.

I would need some kind of metrics in CloudWatch per ECS Service and create an alarm from it.

But I have no clue on how to do it...